# How to define hash tables in Bash?

Tags: bash, dictionary, hashtable, associative-array

What is the equivalent of [Python dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) but in Bash (should work across OS X and Linux).

Comment: Have bash run a python/perl script... That's so much flexible!

Comment: See also: [Associative arrays in Shell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/688849/4561887)

Answer (score 1399, accepted):

## Bash 4

Bash 4 natively supports this feature.  Make sure your script's hashbang is `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or `#!/bin/bash` so you don't end up using `sh`.  Make sure you're either executing your script directly, or execute `script` with `bash script`. (Not actually executing a Bash script with Bash *does* happen, and will be *really* confusing!)

You declare an associative array by doing:

```
declare -A animals
```

You can fill it up with elements using the normal array assignment operator. For example, if you want to have a map of `animal[sound(key)] = animal(value)`:

```
animals=( ["moo"]="cow" ["woof"]="dog")
```

Or declare and instantiate in one line:

```
declare -A animals=( ["moo"]="cow" ["woof"]="dog")
```

Then use them just like normal arrays. Use

- `animals['key']='value'` to set value
- `"${animals[@]}"` to expand the values
- `"${!animals[@]}"` (notice the `!`) to expand the keys

Don't forget to quote them:

```
echo "${animals[moo]}"
for sound in "${!animals[@]}"; do echo "$sound - ${animals[$sound]}"; done
```

## Bash 3

Before bash 4, you don't have associative arrays.  **Do not use `eval` to emulate them**.  Avoid `eval` like the plague, because it *is* the plague of shell scripting.  The most important reason is that `eval` treats your data as executable code (there are many other reasons too).

*First and foremost*: Consider upgrading to bash 4.  This will make the whole process much easier for you.

If there's a reason you can't upgrade, `declare` is a far safer option.  It does not evaluate data as bash code like `eval` does, and as such does not allow arbitrary code injection quite so easily.

Let's prepare the answer by introducing the concepts:

First, indirection.

```
$ animals_moo=cow; sound=moo; i="animals_$sound"; echo "${!i}"
cow
```

Secondly, `declare`:

```
$ sound=moo; animal=cow; declare "animals_$sound=$animal"; echo "$animals_moo"
cow
```

Bring them together:

```
# Set a value:
declare "array_$index=$value"

# Get a value:
arrayGet() { 
    local array=$1 index=$2
    local i="${array}_$index"
    printf '%s' "${!i}"
}
```

Let's use it:

```
$ sound=moo
$ animal=cow
$ declare "animals_$sound=$animal"
$ arrayGet animals "$sound"
cow
```

Note: `declare` cannot be put in a function.  Any use of `declare` inside a bash function turns the variable it creates *local* to the scope of that function, meaning we can't access or modify global arrays with it. (In bash 4 you can use `declare -g` to declare global variables - but in bash 4, you can use associative arrays in the first place, avoiding this workaround.)

Summary:

- Upgrade to bash 4 and use `declare -A` for associative arrays.
- Use the `declare` option if you can't upgrade.
- Consider using `awk` instead and avoid the issue altogether.

Comment: +1 for `declare -A`, I can't believe that I never used it before! I've programmed bash for 10 years.

Comment: I am using bash 4.2, yet ``declare -A`` complains ``-A`` is not a valid option... any ideas why? linux distr is SUSE..

Comment: @Richard: Presumably, you aren't actually using bash.  Is your hashbang sh instead of bash, or are you otherwise invoking your code with sh?  Try putting this right before your declare: echo "$BASH_VERSION $POSIXLY_CORRECT", it should output `4.x` and not `y`.

Comment: Can't upgrade: the only reason I write scripts in Bash is for "run anywhere" portability.  So relying on a non-universal feature of Bash rules this approach out.  Which is a shame, because otherwise it would have been an excellent solution for me!

Comment: @lhunath Continued reliability of existing systems is seen (round here) as more important than new bangs and whistles no-one other than me even perceives the need for yet. Even where I have full freedom, normally I don't upgrade important components like Bash unless the need is really convincing. The answers and advice in several answers here is quite enough to solve my problem without introducing any additional risk!

Comment: @StevePitchers An adequate and also typical answer.  Though at least ponder, what is the additional risk of not upgrading systems - even if it is not an "introduced" risk.  Some consider this "technical debt".

Comment: It's a shame that OSX defaults to Bash 3 still as this represents the "default" for a lot of people. I thought the ShellShock scare might have been the push they needed but apparently not.

Comment: @ken it's a licensing issue. Bash on OSX is stuck at the latest non-GPLv3 licensed build.

Comment: Adding to comments above: OSX is still on Bash version 3.2.57 as of today.

Comment: I only get `0 - dog` when I try your for loop using bash 4.3.30 on ubuntu 14.10

Comment: Thanks, simple `${!i}` indirection does the trick and that's enough. Flaming war in 3, 2, 1…

Comment: Ihnunath, Bash 4 has slower adoption because of GPLv3. Like it or hate it, most would agree that changing all of your licensing or business model is not a "silly excuse".

Comment: *"The future is now, stop living in the past ..."* - That's fine and dandy until OS X reality hits: `$ /bin/bash --version` returns `GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)`. I'm still on OS X 10.8.5 due to operational requirements.

Comment: @jww Apple will not upgrade GNU bash beyond 3 due to its ill will against the GPLv3.  But that should not be a deterrent.  `brew install bash` http://brew.sh/

Comment: ...or [`sudo port install bash`](https://macports.org/), for those (wisely, IMHO) unwilling to make directories in the PATH for all users writable without explicit per-process privilege escalation.

Comment: @lhunath, could you explain the order in which the pairs are stored?

Comment: Bash 4 is a no-no for may developers, especially for embedded devices, due to GPL3 requirements "Protecting your right to tinker" - which is a potential security  nightmare, if you also want to guard against hacks (eg botnet subversion) on your device !

Comment: be careful when looping because **the keys are not visited in the order you may expect** in a loop such as `for sound in "${!animals[@]}"`

Comment: Shouldn't the line **echo "${animals[moo]}"** in the answer have a **$** before **moo**, like **echo "${animals[$moo]}"**?

Comment: @Shabirmean `moo` is not a parameter in this context.  It is a string `"moo"`, the key of the entry in the array that has the value `"cow"`.

Comment: FWIW: if you are thinking about "which Ubuntu version supports bash 4?" (as I was when reading this), it works on _at least_ 14.04 and newer: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=bash

Comment: expanding... if you have `animals_meaw=cat animals_woof=dog animals_moo=cow` you can iterate with `for animal in ${!animals_*}; do echo "the ${!animal} goes ${animal#animals_}"; done` outputs: `the cat goes meaw...`

Comment: ... and if you have `declare -A animals=([meaw]=cat [woof]=dog [moo]=cow)` you can iterate with `for sound in ${!animals[*]}; do echo "the ${animals[$sound]} goes ${sound}"; done` outputs: `the cow goes moo...`

Comment: This also works in ZSH which is the new default command line for Mac.

Comment: "Not actually executing a Bash script with Bash does happen, and will be really confusing!" Truer words were never spoken, especially in the context of the "test" command versus double brackets.

Comment: What a bummer, just spent half an hour upgrading bash on my Mac just to be greeted with a GPLv3 banner upon version check. This might be acceptable for student projects, but for corporate work this is a no go. Should have checked the comment section in advance.

Answer (score 162):

There's parameter substitution, though it may be un-PC as well ...like indirection.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Array pretending to be a Pythonic dictionary
ARRAY=( "cow:moo"
        "dinosaur:roar"
        "bird:chirp"
        "bash:rock" )

for animal in "${ARRAY[@]}" ; do
    KEY="${animal%%:*}"
    VALUE="${animal##*:}"
    printf "%s likes to %s.\n" "$KEY" "$VALUE"
done

printf "%s is an extinct animal which likes to %s\n" "${ARRAY[1]%%:*}" "${ARRAY[1]##*:}"
```

The BASH 4 way is better of course, but if you need a hack ...only a hack will do.
You could search the array/hash with similar techniques.

Comment: I would change that to `VALUE=${animal#*:}` to protect the case where `ARRAY[$x]="caesar:come:see:conquer"`

Comment: It's also useful to put double quotes around the ${ARRAY[@]} in case there are spaces in the keys or values, as in `for animal in "${ARRAY[@]}"; do`

Comment: But isn't the efficiency quite poor? I'm thinking O(n*m) if you want to compare to another list of keys, instead of O(n) with proper hashmaps (constant time lookup, O(1) for a single key).

Comment: The idea is less about efficiency, more about understand/read-ability for those with a background in perl, python or even bash 4. Allows you to write in a similar fashion.

Comment: @CoDEmanX: this is a _hack_, a clever and elegant but still rudimentary _workaround_ to help the poor souls still stuck in 2007 with Bash 3.x. You cannot expect "proper hashmaps" or efficiency considerations in such a simple code.

Comment: i do something similar but slightly different --> each string is separated by a ' '. then i iterate over each line by index and do `words=(${line})` and then i can pick each parameter out of the array `words`

Comment: But the whole point of a hash table or dict its efficiency. You didn't even provide setter or getter interface for this array backed "table"...

Answer (score 136):

This is what I was looking for here:

```
declare -A hashmap
hashmap["key"]="value"
hashmap["key2"]="value2"
echo "${hashmap["key"]}"
for key in ${!hashmap[@]}; do echo $key; done
for value in ${hashmap[@]}; do echo $value; done
echo hashmap has ${#hashmap[@]} elements
```

This did not work for me with bash 4.1.5:

```
animals=( ["moo"]="cow" )
```

Comment: Note, that the value may not contain spaces, otherwise you adde more elements at once

Comment: Upvote for the hashmap["key"]="value" syntax which I, too, found missing from the otherwise fantastic accepted answer.

Comment: @rubo77 key neither, it adds multiple keys. Any way to workaround this?

Comment: An elaboration on the `${!hashmap[@]}` part would be appreciated. The `@` is for getting all the values, I think. But how does it come that the exclamation mark distinguishes between keys and values?

Comment: Shellcheck warns about the `for key in ...` part: `SC2068: Double quote array expansions to avoid re-splitting elements.`

Comment: @lucidbrot I'm sure you have already found this, but just for reference: `${!name[@]} |${!name[*]} =>  If name is an array variable, expands to the list of array indices (keys) assigned in name. If name is not an array, expands to 0 if name is set and null otherwise. When ‘@’ is used and the expansion appears within double quotes, each key expands to a separate word.` [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Answer (score 44):

Just use the file system: the file system is a tree structure that can be used as a hash map.
Your hash table will be a temporary directory, your keys will be filenames, and your values will be file contents. The advantage is that it can handle huge hashmaps, and doesn't require a specific shell.

#### Hashtable creation

`hashtable=$(mktemp -d)`

#### Add an element

`echo $value > "$hashtable/$key"`

#### Read an element

`value=$(< "$hashtable/$key")`

### Performance

Of course, its slow, but not **that** slow.
I tested it on my machine, with an SSD and [btrfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs), and it does around **3000 element read/write per second**.

Comment: Which version of bash supports `mkdir -d`?  (Not 4.3, on Ubuntu 14.  I'd resort to `mkdir /run/shm/foo`, or if that filled up RAM, `mkdir /tmp/foo`.)

Comment: Perhaps `mktemp -d` was meant instead?

Comment: Curious what is the difference between `$value=$(< $hashtable/$key)` and `value=$(< $hashtable/$key)`? Thanks!

Comment: "tested it on my machine" This sounds like a great way to burn a hole through your SSD. Not all Linux distros use tmpfs by default.

Comment: I am processing about 50000 hashes. Perl and PHP do it a hair under 1/2 second. Node in 1 second and something. FS option sounds slow. However, can we make sure that the files only exist in RAM, somehow?

Comment: Yes. In linux, you can put the files in /dev/shm, for instance. See https://www.howtoforge.com/storing-files-directories-in-memory-with-tmpfs

Comment: I like this solution a lot. It is very common to need only handful of (< 100) elements because it makes the code more straightforward. If you need many thousands, probably best to use Python, Perl, whatever.

Comment: This won't work with values that has "/" slashes in them

Comment: @zomars, you can escape the slashes.
OP, I'm sure there must be a way to represent a "deep hash" (hierarchy of hashes) in a deep directory structure that is saved to and accessed from /dev/shm!

Answer (score 30):

You can further modify the hput()/hget() interface so that you have named hashes as follows:

```
hput() {
    eval "$1""$2"='$3'
}

hget() {
    eval echo '${'"$1$2"'#hash}'
}
```

and then

```
hput capitals France Paris
hput capitals Netherlands Amsterdam
hput capitals Spain Madrid
echo `hget capitals France` and `hget capitals Netherlands` and `hget capitals Spain`
```

This lets you define other maps that don't conflict (e.g., 'rcapitals' which does country lookup by capital city). But, either way, I think you'll find that this is all pretty terrible, performance-wise.

***EDIT***: Modified version of above that supports keys with non-alphanumeric characters

```bash
hashKey() {
  # replace non-alphanumeric characters with underscore to make keys valid BASH identifiers
  echo "$1_$2" | sed -E "s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/_/g" | sed -E "s/^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+|[^a-zA-Z0-9]+\$//g"
}

hashPut() {
  local KEY=`hashKey $1 $2`
  eval "$KEY"="$3"
}

hashGet() {
  local KEY=`hashKey $1 $2`
  echo "${!KEY}"
}
```

***END EDIT***

If you really want fast hash lookup, there's a terrible, terrible hack that actually works really well. It is this: write your key/values out to a temporary file, one-per line, then use 'grep "^$key"' to get them out, using pipes with cut or awk or sed or whatever to retrieve the values.

Like I said, it sounds terrible, and it sounds like it ought to be slow and do all sorts of unnecessary IO, but in practice it is very fast (disk cache is awesome, ain't it?), even for very large hash tables. You have to enforce key uniqueness yourself, etc. Even if you only have a few hundred entries, the output file/grep combo is going to be quite a bit faster - in my experience several times faster. It also eats less memory.

Here's one way to do it:

```
hinit() {
    rm -f /tmp/hashmap.$1
}

hput() {
    echo "$2 $3" >> /tmp/hashmap.$1
}

hget() {
    grep "^$2 " /tmp/hashmap.$1 | awk '{ print $2 };'
}

hinit capitals
hput capitals France Paris
hput capitals Netherlands Amsterdam
hput capitals Spain Madrid

echo `hget capitals France` and `hget capitals Netherlands` and `hget capitals Spain`
```

Comment: Great! you can even iterate it:
for i in $(compgen -A variable capitols); do
 hget "$i" ""
done

Answer (score 24):

Consider a solution using the bash builtin **read** as illustrated within the code snippet from a ufw firewall script that follows. This approach has the advantage of using as many delimited field sets (not just 2) as are desired.  We have used the **|** delimiter because port range specifiers may require a colon, ie **6001:6010**.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readonly connections=(       
                            '192.168.1.4/24|tcp|22'
                            '192.168.1.4/24|tcp|53'
                            '192.168.1.4/24|tcp|80'
                            '192.168.1.4/24|tcp|139'
                            '192.168.1.4/24|tcp|443'
                            '192.168.1.4/24|tcp|445'
                            '192.168.1.4/24|tcp|631'
                            '192.168.1.4/24|tcp|5901'
                            '192.168.1.4/24|tcp|6566'
)

function set_connections(){
    local range proto port
    for fields in ${connections[@]}
    do
            IFS=$'|' read -r range proto port <<< "$fields"
            ufw allow from "$range" proto "$proto" to any port "$port"
    done
}

set_connections
```

Comment: @CharlieMartin : read is a very powerful feature and is under-utilized by many bash programmers.  It allows compact forms of _lisp-like_ list processing.  For example, in the above example we can strip off just the first element and retain the rest (ie a similar concept to _first_ and _rest_ in lisp) by doing: `IFS=$'|' read -r first rest <<< "$fields"`

Answer (score 20):

```
hput () {
  eval hash"$1"='$2'
}

hget () {
  eval echo '${hash'"$1"'#hash}'
}
hput France Paris
hput Netherlands Amsterdam
hput Spain Madrid
echo `hget France` and `hget Netherlands` and `hget Spain`
```

---

```
$ sh hash.sh
Paris and Amsterdam and Madrid
```

Comment: Sigh, that seems unnecessarily insulting and it's inaccurate anyway. One would not put input validation, escaping, or encoding (see, I actually do know) in the guts of the hash table, but rather in a wrapper and as soon as possible after input.

Comment: @DigitalRoss can you explain what is the use of  #hash in *eval echo '${hash'"$1"'#hash}'*. for me it seems me as a comment not more then that. does #hash have any special meaning here?

Comment: @Sanjay `${var#start}` removes the text *start* from the beginning of the value stored in the variable *var*.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with @lhunath and others that the associative array are the way to go with Bash 4. If you are stuck to Bash 3 (OSX, old distros that you cannot update) you can use also expr, which should be everywhere, a string and regular expressions. I like it especially when the dictionary is not too big.

1. Choose 2 separators that you will not use in keys and values (e.g. ',' and ':' )
2. Write your map as a string (note the separator ',' also at beginning and end)

   ```
   animals=",moo:cow,woof:dog,"
   ```
3. Use a regex to extract the values

   ```
   get_animal {
       echo "$(expr "$animals" : ".*,$1:\([^,]*\),.*")"
   }
   ```
4. Split the string to list the items

   ```
   get_animal_items {
       arr=$(echo "${animals:1:${#animals}-2}" | tr "," "\n")
       for i in $arr
       do
           value="${i##*:}"
           key="${i%%:*}"
           echo "${value} likes to $key"
       done
   }
   ```

Now you can use it:

```
$ animal = get_animal "moo"
cow
$ get_animal_items
cow likes to moo
dog likes to woof
```

Answer (score 6):

I really liked Al P's answer but wanted uniqueness enforced cheaply so I took it one step further - use a directory. There are some obvious limitations (directory file limits, invalid file names) but it should work for most cases.

```
hinit() {
    rm -rf /tmp/hashmap.$1
    mkdir -p /tmp/hashmap.$1
}

hput() {
    printf "$3" > /tmp/hashmap.$1/$2
}

hget() {
    cat /tmp/hashmap.$1/$2
}

hkeys() {
    ls -1 /tmp/hashmap.$1
}

hdestroy() {
    rm -rf /tmp/hashmap.$1
}

hinit ids

for (( i = 0; i < 10000; i++ )); do
    hput ids "key$i" "value$i"
done

for (( i = 0; i < 10000; i++ )); do
    printf '%s\n' $(hget ids "key$i") > /dev/null
done

hdestroy ids
```

It also performs a tad bit better in my tests.

```
$ time bash hash.sh 
real    0m46.500s
user    0m16.767s
sys     0m51.473s

$ time bash dirhash.sh 
real    0m35.875s
user    0m8.002s
sys     0m24.666s
```

Just thought I'd pitch in. Cheers!

Edit: Adding hdestroy()

Answer (score 5):

A coworker just mentioned this thread.  I've independently implemented hash tables within bash, and it's not dependent on version 4.  From a blog post of mine in March 2010 (before some of the answers here...) entitled [Hash tables in bash](https://web.archive.org/web/20100405100718/http://khopesh.com/blog/adam-katz-musings/bash-hash):

I [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12945518/2) used `cksum` to hash but have since translated [Java's string hashCode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7616484/519360) to native bash/zsh.

```sh
# Here's the hashing function
ht() {
  local h=0 i
  for (( i=0; i < ${#1}; i++ )); do
    let "h=( (h<<5) - h ) + $(printf %d \'${1:$i:1})"
    let "h |= h"
  done
  printf "$h"
}

# Example:

myhash[`ht foo bar`]="a value"
myhash[`ht baz baf`]="b value"

echo ${myhash[`ht baz baf`]} # "b value"
echo ${myhash[@]} # "a value b value" though perhaps reversed
echo ${#myhash[@]} # "2" - there are two values (note, zsh doesn't count right)
```

It's not bidirectional, and the built-in way is a lot better, but neither should really be used anyway.  Bash is for quick one-offs, and such things should quite rarely involve complexity that might require hashes, except perhaps in your `~/.bashrc` and friends.

Comment: The link in the answer is scary! If you click it, you are stuck in a redirection loop. Please update.

Comment: @MohammadRakibAmin – Yeah, my website is down and I doubt I'll be resurrecting my blog. I have updated the above link to an archived version. Thanks for your interest!

Comment: It doesn't look like this will handle hash collisions.

Comment: @neuralmer – True. This was designed to be an actual **hash** implementation of a hash structure. If you want to handle hash collisions, I recommend a real hash implementation rather than a hack like this. Adapting this to manage collisions would remove all of its elegance.

Comment: Here's a version which uses your `ht()` function and handles collisions: https://gist.github.com/chr15m/fb257ae8bb9774245b0ec67d9c7d388b

Comment: @ChrisMcCormick – Good start, but your version lacks the speed of a hash lookup (it loops through all values) and doesn't actually implement any collision avoidance. I've [commented on your gist](https://gist.github.com/chr15m/fb257ae8bb9774245b0ec67d9c7d388b?permalink_comment_id=4533677#gistcomment-4533677) with more detail.

Answer (score 3):

Two things, you can use memory instead of /tmp in any kernel 2.6 by using /dev/shm (Redhat) other distros may vary. Also hget can be reimplemented using read as follows:

```
function hget {

  while read key idx
  do
    if [ $key = $2 ]
    then
      echo $idx
      return
    fi
  done < /dev/shm/hashmap.$1
}
```

In addition by assuming that all keys are unique, the return short circuits the read loop and prevents having to read through all entries. If your implementation can have duplicate keys, then simply leave out the return. This saves the expense of reading and forking both grep and awk. Using /dev/shm for both implementations yielded the following using time hget on a 3 entry hash searching for the last entry :

Grep/Awk:

```
hget() {
    grep "^$2 " /dev/shm/hashmap.$1 | awk '{ print $2 };'
}

$ time echo $(hget FD oracle)
3

real    0m0.011s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.013s
```

Read/echo:

```
$ time echo $(hget FD oracle)
3

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.004s
```

on multiple invocations I never saw less then a 50% improvement. 
This can all be attributed to fork over head, due to the use of `/dev/shm`.

Answer (score 2):

Prior to bash 4 there is no good way to use associative arrays in bash. Your best bet is to use an interpreted language that actually has support for such things, like awk. On the other hand, bash 4 *does* support them.

As for *less* good ways in bash 3, here is a reference than might help: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006

Answer (score 2):

Bash 3 solution:

In reading some of the answers I put together a quick little function I would like to contribute back that might help others.

```
# Define a hash like this
MYHASH=("firstName:Milan"
        "lastName:Adamovsky")

# Function to get value by key
getHashKey()
 {
  declare -a hash=("${!1}")
  local key
  local lookup=$2

  for key in "${hash[@]}" ; do
   KEY=${key%%:*}
   VALUE=${key#*:}
   if [[ $KEY == $lookup ]]
   then
    echo $VALUE
   fi
  done
 }

# Function to get a list of all keys
getHashKeys()
 {
  declare -a hash=("${!1}")
  local KEY
  local VALUE
  local key
  local lookup=$2

  for key in "${hash[@]}" ; do
   KEY=${key%%:*}
   VALUE=${key#*:}
   keys+="${KEY} "
  done

  echo $keys
 }

# Here we want to get the value of 'lastName'
echo $(getHashKey MYHASH[@] "lastName")


# Here we want to get all keys
echo $(getHashKeys MYHASH[@])
```

Comment: I think this is a pretty neat snippet. It could use a little cleanup (not much, though). In my version, I've renamed 'key' to 'pair' and made KEY and VALUE lowercase (because I use uppercase when variables are exported). I also renamed getHashKey to getHashValue and made both key and value local (sometimes you would want them not to be local, though). In getHashKeys, I do not assign anything to value. I use semicolon for separation, since my values are URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rather contrived but hopefully instructive hash/map/dictionary/associative array example. Let's say I have an array of strings and I'd like to create a mapping from each word to a count of times it appears in the array.

Sure, there are ways to do this with piped commands, but the point is to illustrate the core map operations: checking existence of a key with `-v`, adding key-value mappings, retrieving the value for a key, updating the existing value for a key and looping over the whole map to print the key-value pairs.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash
set -o pipefail

bash --version | head -1

words=(foo foo bar bar foo baz baz foo bar)
declare -A counter=() # create the map

for word in "${words[@]}"; do
    # if the key doesn't yet exist in the map, add it
    if [[ ! -v counter[$word] ]]; then
        counter[$word]=0
    fi

    # look up the value of a key, add one, and store back in the map
    counter[$word]=$((${counter[$word]} + 1))
done

# iterate the map
for key in "${!counter[@]}"; do
    echo "$key ${counter[$key]}"
done
```

Output:

```
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
foo 4
bar 3
baz 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I also used the bash4 way but I find and annoying bug.

I needed to update dynamically the associative array content so i used this way:

```
for instanceId in $instanceList
do
   aws cloudwatch describe-alarms --output json --alarm-name-prefix $instanceId| jq '.["MetricAlarms"][].StateValue'| xargs | grep -E 'ALARM|INSUFFICIENT_DATA'
   [ $? -eq 0 ] && statusCheck+=([$instanceId]="checkKO") || statusCheck+=([$instanceId]="allCheckOk"
done
```

I find out that with bash 4.3.11 appending to an existing key in the dict resulted in appending the value if already present. So for example after some repetion the content of the value was "checkKOcheckKOallCheckOK" and this was not good.

No problem with bash 4.3.39 where appenging an existent key means to substisture the actuale value if already present.

I solved this just cleaning/declaring the statusCheck associative array before the cicle:

```
unset statusCheck; declare -A statusCheck
```