# Perl hash equivalent in bash scripting?

Tags: shell, hash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to define hash tables in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494178/how-to-define-hash-tables-in-bash)

Perl hash equivalent in bash ? 
Please let me know.

Following code is working perfectly in korn shell, however not in bash [3.2 version], getting error for typeset.

```
#!/bin/ksh 
typeset -A newmap 
name="mandar"
id="111515" 
newmap["name"]=$name
newmap["id"]=$id 
echo "${newmap["id"]}"
```

Comment: Following code is working perfectly in korn shell, however not in bash [3.2 version], getting error for typeset.                    `#!/bin/ksh
typeset -A newmap
name="mandar"
id="111515"

newmap["name"]=$name
newmap["id"]=$id

echo "${newmap["id"]}"`

Answer (score 1):

Use `declare -A` instead of `typeset -A` if you're running Bash 4 or better. I tested it and it works correctly that way.

Alternatively you could test for bash and create an alias so you can run the rest of the script unmodified (probably):

```
alias typeset=declare
```

Comment: @mandy: you're right, I forgot to say that this works on Bash 4 and higher. Mine's Bash 4.2.