# Accessing bash array keys (mac)

Tags: macos, bash, unix

For some reason, I am unable to access the array keys with the exclamation point syntax:

```
declare -a sites
sites=(["fr"]="frederick" ["an"]="annapolis")

for i in "${!sites[@]}"
  do
    echo "key: $i "
  done
```

This Just echo's out "key : 0"

What am I doing wrong here?

Also, I would like to add the value.

So the our put would be:

key : fr , value : frederick

Answer (score 0):

It *Can* be done in old bash versions.

In older versions of bash you can use the whole environment variable set to implement associative arrays (also called hashes)

```
export HASH_PREFIX="I_AM_A_HASH"

hash-set() {
    HASH_NAME="$1" ; shift
    HASH_KEY="$1"  ; shift
    HASH_VAL="$1"  ; shift
    eval "export ${HASH_PREFIX}_${HASH_NAME}_KEY_${HASH_KEY}='$HASH_VAL'"
}
hash-get() {
    HASH_NAME="$1" ; shift
    HASH_KEY="$1"  ; shift
    eval "echo \"\$${HASH_PREFIX}_${HASH_NAME}_KEY_${HASH_KEY}\""
}
hash-keys() {
    HASH_NAME="$1" ; shift
    HASH_PREFIX_NAME_LENGTH=$(( ${#HASH_PREFIX} + ${#HASH_NAME} + 6 ))
    declare -x | while read -r LINE_READ ; do
        LINE_READ="${LINE_READ:11}"
        if [   x"${LINE_READ:0:HASH_PREFIX_NAME_LENGTH}" \
             = x"${HASH_PREFIX}_${HASH_NAME}_KEY_" \
           ]
        then
            LINE_READ="${LINE_READ:HASH_PREFIX_NAME_LENGTH}"
            LINE_READ="${LINE_READ/=*/}"
           echo "${LINE_READ}"
        fi
    done
}

hash-set sites "fr" "frederick"
hash-set sites "an" "annapolis"

for i in $(hash-keys sites) ; do
    echo "key: $i, value: $(hash-get sites $i)"
done
```

The keys are restricted to the same characters as Environment Variables (0-9,a-z,A-Z,_).

You could workaround by using "_xx" to mean non-alphanumeric ascii values (example "_5f" for "_" and "_3f" for "?").  rosettacode has how to convert back and forth between ascii characters and hex in pure-bash.

Also on mac laptop you can install homebrew then use it to install a newer bash.
You could also use the full associative arrays in awk or perl or ruby or python.

Comment: Please do __not__ use `eval`, instead see [@lhunath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3467959/2632107)'s work-around for Bash version that predate `4`.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is `declare -a`.

As per the man page, it should be `declare -A`.

```
declare [-aAfFgilrtux] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
    ...
    -a     Each name is an indexed array variable (see Arrays above).
    -A     Each name is an associative array variable (see Arrays above).
```

Try this instead:

```
declare -A sites
sites=(["fr"]="frederick" ["an"]="annapolis")

for i in "${!sites[@]}"
  do
    echo "key: $i, value: ${sites[$i]}"
  done
```

Comment: That was what I tried at first. But if I run the script you posted, I get this output:  line 3: declare: -A: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
key: 0, value: annapolis

Comment: This might be helpful as well: bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)

Comment: Associative arrays require bash >= 4.0.  See http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS.  And the fact that your man pages for bash 3.2 don't say anything about associative arrays. ;-)

Comment: @Mikel, the question was tagged `macos`, which is always bash 3.2 unless "special measures" (like [macports](https://macports.org/) or [brew](https://brew.sh)) are taken.

Answer (score -1):

I think it maybe a lack of capitalization getting in the way...

```sh
declare -A _sites=( ["fr"]="frederick" ["an"]="annapolis" )

for i in "${!_sites[@]}"; do
    printf '%s -> %s\n' "${i}" "${_sites[$i]}"
done
```

---

Resources that where helpful in sorting the above out are not limited to the following;

- An answer from [@anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28179520/2632107) regarding `declare -A` usage
- An answer from [@lhunath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3467959/2632107) that also covers a work around for Bash versions `3` or lower.

> After reading the other posted answer's comments I think you'll want that last listed answer's work-around if stuck with older version of Bash that cannot be updated for *reasons*.

---

[@Fenn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55976763/2632107) a few more notes...

```sh
hash-set() {
    HASH_NAME="$1" ; shift
    HASH_KEY="$1"  ; shift
    HASH_VAL="$1"  ; shift
    eval "export ${HASH_PREFIX}_${HASH_NAME}_KEY_${HASH_KEY}='$HASH_VAL'"
}
```

... without `shift`ing, or `eval`, and with required arguments might look like...

```sh
hash_set(){
    local _name="${1:?${FUNCNAME[0]} not provided a Hash Name}"
    local _key="${2:?${FUNCNAME[0]} not provided a Hash Key}"
    local _value="${3:?${FUNCNAME[0]} not provided a Value}"
    declare -g "${HASH_PREFIX}_${_name}_KEY_${_key}='${_value}'"
}
```

... hopefully this is a bit more helpful in translating that answer into something that can be up-voted.