# Listing only name and size of the file with largest size (UNIX)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix

How can I **only** list the name and the size of the largest file size in a directory I used this command but It didn't work when I tried on a different directories.

```
find . -type f -exec ls -lS {} \; | sort -t" " -n -k5 | cut -d" " -f5,10 | tail -n1
```

Comment: Don't you want to look for type d?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -printf '%s %p\n'|sort -nr|head -n 1
```

the number 1 after head -n means how many of the largest files it'll output and if you want to find files in sub-directories as well you can do that by removing the -maxdepth 1 or changing the number to a larger one.

for more info see the replies in this earlier post: [How to find the largest file in a directory and its subdirectories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522269/how-to-find-the-largest-file-in-a-directory-and-its-subdirectories)

For posts about this kind of stuff i suggest tagging them as bash, sh or shell.

Comment: Please don't answer duplicates; instead, leave a comment indicating that the question is a duplicate. Once you earn enough reputation points, you will also be able to participate in voting to close as a duplicate (and eventually, if you earn a gold badge in one of the tags, you can unilaterally close as a duplicate, like I did here).