# How to export array as environment variable in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

How to export array??

in a shell script:

```
id=()
id+=( id id2 id3 )
password=()
password+=( password password2 password3 )

export $id

export $password
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to export an associative array (hash) in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944674/how-to-export-an-associative-array-hash-in-bash)

Comment: https://www.mail-archive.com/bug-bash@gnu.org/msg01774.html

Comment: Array or not: The syntax is `export variableName` not `export $variableName` (which is basically `export content of the variable`).