# Nested HashMaps in Linux Shell?

Tags: shell, hashmap

Can I have nested Associative Maps in Linux Shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes!

Take a look at `man bash`!

(search for *associative*)

But if you want to assign array to array, you have to declare sub objects for itself, whit his own handler, than you may assign this handler as a string to upper array:

```
declare -A x
declare -A x_foo
x_foo=([a]=1 [b]=3)
x['foo']=x_foo;
```

so

```
echo ${!x[@]}
foo

echo ${x[foo]}
x_foo

eval echo \${${x[foo]}[a]}
1

eval echo \${${x[foo]}[b]}
3

eval echo \${!${x[foo]}[@]}
a b

eval echo \${${x[foo]}[@]}
1 3
```

Comment: It is mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3467959/1460043 that usage of `eval` to simulate associative arrays has issues.

Answer (score 5):

No, bash array are only one dimensional. You should be able to construct your array keys to fake multi-dimensionality. For example, if you want the JSON object

```
x = {'foo': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 'bar': {'c': 3, 'd', 4}}
```

in bash, you would have to do something like

```
declare -A x
x[foo,a]=1
x[foo,b]=2
x[bar,c]=3
x[bar,d]=4
```

and reference with, for example

```
i=foo
j=b
echo "${x[$i,$j]}"
```