# How to create dictionary using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file status.txt which is in the following format:

```
1|A|B
2|C|D
```

Now i have to read this file in shell script and create a dictionary like:

```
dictionary['1'] = ['A', 'B']
dictionary['2'] = ['C', 'D']
```

I am able read the content of file using this:

```
while read line
    do
        key=$line | cut --d="|" -f1
        data1=$line | cut --d="|" -f2
        data2=$line | cut --d="|" -f3
    done < "status.txt"
```

Can anybody help me in creating the dictionary as mentioned above.

Comment: I don't understand how your directory structure should look. What is wrong with `mkdir`?

Comment: This might get you going in the right direction:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494178/how-to-define-hash-tables-in-bash

Comment: value=\`echo "dictionary\[\'$key\'\]\ \=\ \[\'$data1\',\ \'$data2\'\]"\`, then mkdir $value, i think this will help

Comment: The OP said "dictionary", not "directory".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According your idea with while loop, here is the fix:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS="|" read -r key data1 data2
do 
  echo "dictionary['${key}'] = ['${data1}', '${data2}']"
done <"status.txt"
```

Comment: I did that now how to access the dictionary elements? Should I say `echo $dictionary['2']` to access `C` and `D`?

Answer (score 1):

Change your assignment lines to be like this:

```
key=$(echo $line | cut -d"|" -f1)
```

And then add the following line

```
printf "dictionary['%d'] = ['%s', '%s']\n" $key $data1 $data2
```

Answer (score 1):

```perl
#!awk -f
BEGIN {
  FS = "|"
}
{
  printf "dictionary['%s'] = ['%s', '%s']\n", $1, $2, $3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the previous answers i could figure out a solution

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS="|" read -r key data1 data2
do 
  echo "{'${key}' : {'${data1}', '${data2}'}},"
done <"status.txt"
```

So it will give the result something like as follows

```
{'key1' : {'data1', 'data2'}, 'key2' : {'data1', 'data2'}}
```

Then you can use this result in any other language.
Example: Python - Convert the above dictionary string to json by 
`1. json.dumps(result)` to convert single quotes tto double quotes 
`2. json.loads(result)` to convert string to json