# Can I define an object as a variable in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I know how to store a string as a variable, for example: `API="http://localhost:4741"`

However, for the sake of a CURL request I would like to be able to store on object as a variable that I can access values on, something like `OBJ="{name : Joe}"`. Is this possible?

Right now my CURL request looks like this:

```
curl --include --request POST localhost:3000/scrape \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{
    "url": "http://www.oddsshark.com/stats/gamelog/basketball/nba/20736",
    "team": "LA Clippers"
  }'
```

I would like to be able to do something like this, using a dictionary or an object:

```
TEAM=( ["Clippers"]="http://www.oddsshark.com/stats/gamelog/basketball/nba/20736" )
curl --include --request POST localhost:3000/scrape \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{
    "url": "http://www.oddsshark.com/stats/gamelog/basketball/nba/20736",
    "team": "${TEAM[Clippers]}"
  }'
```

Comment: Add output of your curl request to your question.

Comment: Would something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494178/how-to-define-hash-tables-in-bash) work?

Comment: You can. And then use `jq` to parse the JSON. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools)

Comment: *Updated. I tried what you suggested @0x5453 to no avail, maybe I need to update my bash though

Comment: So I'm actually using zsh rather than bash - will this prevent me from using the solution provided by @0x5453 ?

Comment: @BenMelito Looks like the [syntax](http://hyperpolyglot.org/unix-shells#associative-arrays) is mostly the same.  Note that if this is in a script, you can always set bash as the interpreter for the script, even if you are running from zsh: `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much @0x5453