# (Bash) How to monitor file changes within a directory (Creation, Deletion, Renaming)

Tags: linux, bash

I have been trying to tackle this problem for a few days before resorting to a vague question. I'm aware of tools such as **inotify** however as part of an assignment i am not allowed to use tools that do it for you.  I used `watch -n 5 -d ls -l` to visually show the changes.  However this is not what i'm looking for.  I would like to print the changes to the terminal when files within a directory get deleted, created, or renamed.  I am not looking for an outright solution, just some suggestions on how i should try tackle this problem.

Comment: `inotify` IS the right tool

Comment: Inotify does work perfectly but i am not allowed to use tools like that.

Comment: What's the problem with using `watch`? Also, if you really can't use watch, perhaps your own bash script could be created. How about a simple script that runs every X seconds, does a `ls`, dumps output to a file and `diff`s it with previously written file. Output of ls and diff can be customized as needed.

Comment: If you have to use bash only, there's not much you can do.  You'll need to call things like `watch` and `ls`, and there's absolutely no distinction between those tools and `inotifywait`, so you might as well use inotifywait.

Comment: To echo the other commentators, that's an odd and very difficult assignment. It seems like Bash-only is intended to be literal, i.e., meaning no external commands, e.g., requiring the use of shell globbing instead of running a command like `ls`. For such a complex task, Bash is not very practical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to accomplish this is probably by using the [inodes](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-unixlinux-filesystem-inodes.html) of the files in the targeted directory as an identifier to track changes. For example, you could build a [hash table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494178/how-to-define-hash-tables-in-bash) when your script starts by storing the inode as the identifier and using the file name as the key. once the initial table is built, the program will loop back over the directory & table again checking for the following;

- Has an inode disappeared? If so, the key that has an identifier == to that effected inode has been
  deleted.
- Do the identifiers and keys still match up with the directory? if not then files have been renamed.
- And finally, is there a new inode showing up in the directory? if so a new file has been created so we will need to add it and its filename to the table.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Great thinking, i will make a start at this solution now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the change immediately?

If not, a bash script is enough, there should be a loop in the script, check all the files in the directory, if it is not the same with the last check, then output something, then continue.

Comment: The problem is i don't understand how to specify if the change was a file creation, deletion or rename.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not using the tools written for the intended purpose (e.g. `inotifywait`) does make things a bit more interesting.... What can tell you whether a file has been modified or not? (hint: how about something that can give a unique fingerprint of each file?) Not the fastest thing in the world, but a `md5sum` will certainly do that for you. A simple redirection of the results will do:

```
$ md5sum yourdir/* > yourdir.md5
```

How to notice if a file has been added, removed, or changed in some way? You would need a way to compare the checksums for each file at some given interval. You can simply use the `--check` option for `md5sum`, but that will not catch new or removed files, only changed files. What else could compare and identify any new, removed or changed files? `diff` comes to mind.

What if you create a new listing say:

```
$ md5sum yourdir/* > yourcheck.md5
```

and then call `diff` to compare the checksum listings?

```
$ diff yourdir.md5 yourcheck.md5
```

Based on the simple `diff` output you could determine if a file was added, removed, or changed. For the next iteration, you could simply copy `yourcheck.md5` to `yourdir.md5` (so it holds the current checksums for the directory) and then repeat your check at the next interval.

You can also use variations of options for `diff` to simply check for changes without creating output, etc. depending on how you want to handle the flow of you script.

Now this isn't the only way to approach the problem, but is can be a simple way to do it using only `md5sum` and `diff`.

You can do something very similar replacing `md5sum` with `stat` and storing file mod-times, etc. You will just have to see if there is any speed benefit to be gained using one verses the other. (though I suspect simply picking off the mod time for each file would be much quicker than generating a `md5sum` of each file)

There are many other ways to capture the state of the files in a directory. (for that matter, you can just redirect a directory listing that includes the date and time, e.g. `ls -al` into a file and `diff` that without relying on `md5sum` or `stat` to capture the same information in a different form). See what you can come up with.

The key will be to `diff` two versions of something. What... is up to you.