# Check if bash array values are all same

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, unix, sh

I have a bash array "RUN_Arr" with values as given below. If the values are same, I want the script to continue else I want to report them.

```
echo "${RUN_Arr[@]}"
"AHVY37BCXY" "AHVY37BCXY" "AHVY37BCXY" "AHVY38BCXY" "AHVY37BCXY" "AHVY37BCXY"
```

Based on the above array, I want to echo:

```
 No the array values are not same
 "AHVY37BCXY" "AHVY38BCXY"
```

Can someone suggest a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Iterate through your array, and test against a *watermark*:

```
arr=(a a a b a a a)

watermark=${arr[0]}
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
    if [[ "$watermark" != "$i" ]]; then
        not_equal=true
        break
    fi
done

[[ -n "$not_equal" ]] && echo "They are not equal ..."
```

Very simplistic Proof-Of-Concept for you; obviously harden as appropriate for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I was thinking the same approach. I am wondering if there is a function that gets the unique element in an array if so, I can report if the number of unique elements is more than one.

Comment: There's no such function, per se, but that doesn't mean you couldn't write one for yourself.  I might use Awk, outsource to a different language, or Bash's hash tables.  Check out [How to define hash tables in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494178/how-to-define-hash-tables-in-bash)

Answer (score 4):

If none of your array elements includes a newline character, you can do this:

```
mapfile -t uniq < <(printf "%s\n" "${RUN_Arr[@]}" | sort -u)
if (( ${#uniq[@]} > 1 )); then
    echo "The elements are not the same: ${uniq[@]}" 
    # ...
```

If you need to protect against elements with newline characters, there is a simple solution if you have bash 4.4 (for the `-d` option) and Gnu or FreeBSD sort (for the `-z` option):

```
mapfile -d '' -t uniq < <(printf "%s\n" "${RUN_Arr[@]}" | sort -zu)
if (( ${#uniq[@]} > 1 )); then
    echo "The elements are not the same: ${uniq[@]}" 
    exit 1
fi
```

Without bash 4.4, you could use an adaptation of @hunteke's answer:

```
for i in "${RUN_Arr[@]:1}"; do
    if [[ $i != ${RUN_ARR[0]} ]]; then
        printf "The elements are not the same:"
        printf "%s\0" "${RUN_Arr[@]}" |
            sort -zu |
            xargs -0 printf " %s"
        printf "\n"
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

(This still requires a sort which supports `-z`.)

Comment: Thanks Rici, that's is very helpful.