# Need to load local variables into an associative array in Bash

Tags: bash, associative-array, local-variables

I am building a provisioning script that fills in variables, from where they are centrally defined in a bash file, into various non-bash files (sql, nginx, etc.) as a part of spinning up a VM.

What I need is to build an associative array thats populated with my local variables.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
var1=abc
var2=123
var3=xyz
declare -A vars_list

#magic script would produce this:
vars_list=([var1]=$var1 [var2]=$var2 [var3]=$var3)

#print out
for i in "${!vars_list[@]}"
do
  echo "key  : $i"
  echo "value: ${vars_list[$i]}"
done
```

will yield:

key  : var1
value: abc
key  : var3
value: xyz
key  : var2
value: 123

Been trying this for way too long. Seems like this is another thing that bash just cannot do simply. Help?

Comment: Did you see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494178/how-to-define-hash-tables-in-bash)? What version of bash (`bash --version`)?

Comment: Why do you need it? Where are the variable names coming from?

Comment: @jeremysprofile are you referencing associative arrays? The primary issue here is pulling out all the local variables dynamically, not manually. Not sure if thats what you were referencing.

Bash version is 4.2

Comment: @choroba, I need it because I am trying to set all the variables in a build script in one place. The build script (bash) takes those env variables and puts them into sql build files, nginx files and potentially other domains as well - ones that don't have a direct interface in bash. I could technically embed it all in bash, but it would be very messy and I just don't do that.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't run `set -a` ahead-of-time to export those variables to the environment when they're created? That would enable some simpler techniques (such as `while IFS== read -r -d '' key val; do array[$key]=$val; done < <(cat /proc/self/environ)`).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.

```
var1=abc
var2=123
var3=xyz
declare -A vars_list

#magic script would produce this:
vars_index=('var1' 'var2' 'var3')
for ((i=0;i<${#vars_index[@]};i++))
do
    vars_list["${vars_index[i]}"]="${!vars_index[i]}"
done

#print out
for i in "${!vars_list[@]}"
do
    echo "key  : $i"
    echo "value : ${vars_list[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: Thanks, thats definitely half of it. However the hard part is getting the list of local variables dynamically (in other words, without the assistance of the vars_index). I've tried several different methods, including "declare", "printenv", "set" and "env", but none of them seem to have a clean avenue to getting what I need.

Answer (score 0):

How is

```
var1=abc
var2=123
var3=xyz
```

better than

```
declare -A vars_list
vars_list=(
    [var1]=abc
    [var2]=123
    [var3]=xyz
)
```

? Just assign to the associative array directly.

Comment: I'm looking for a dynamic build, not a manual build. See Charles Duffy's response.

Comment: I think it's the best approach. Are you interested in var like BASHPID, OPTIND or LS_COLORS?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare -A vars
while IFS= read -r var; do
  vars[$var]=${!var}
done < <(compgen -v)
```

`compgen -v` lists currently-defined variables (names only, no values, avoiding the parsing difficulties present with `set` and uncontrolled values).

Comment: This looks promising, but I cannot get it to run without error. I'm not familiar with the "< <(... )" syntax on the done line to troubleshoot it.