# Want to separate list of dictionaries not separated by comma

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures

I have a text file of dictionaries, these dictionaries are not separated by commas, is it possible to separate them and get nice elements in a list, with each element representing a dictionary.

E.g. : what I have: {} {} {}

What I want [{}, {}, {}]

Can someone please suggest the best way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: `sed -i 's/^/[/ ; s/$/]/ ; s/} {/}, {/g' filename.txt`

Comment: Thanks, that did exactly what I wished for.

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Comment: I request you to kindly post that as an answer it will be really helpful and easy to find for others looking for the same

Comment: I request you kindly accept my answer.

Comment: Just hope you don't have nested dictionaries.

Comment: Yes that I am thinking, will be an issue, as I move to more complex structures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily done with `sed(1)`. Assuming filename.txt is the name of file with dictionaries, the invocation is

```
sed -i 's/^/[/ ; s/$/]/ ; s/} {/}, {/g' filename.txt
```

Comment: is there way to use it in python script without using subprocess

Answer (score 1):

I am new to coding but I think instead of trying to convert a text to dictionaries, you can just change the data-structure to an associative array.

Not sure if it will help you but this is something that helped me under similar circumstances.

[dictionaries style database in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494178/how-to-define-hash-tables-in-bash)

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I wished to do, It was an automatic feed, sadly I can't change the data structure.