# Hashmap-style array in shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm new to shell. I want to create a hashmap-style array.

I already took a look at this [How to define hash tables in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494178/how-to-define-hash-tables-in-bash)

It's not exactly what I want. 
This is what I expect:

```
myArray=(emma=paris, london, ny john=tokyo, LA)

#names are my keys and cities are my values
```

My actual code is like:

```
 declare -A myArray=( ["$names"]="$cities" )
```

It doesn't work because each new city overwrites the last one.

Comment: `declare -A array=( [key]=value )`  isn't expected to add new values to an existing array, it just replaces the whole thing. Use `array[$key]=$value` to modify an array (one that was *previously* declared associative with `declare -A array` if necessary) rather than replacing it outright.

Answer (score 0):

danaso, did you quote the list of cities for each person, or did you quote each city individually? Things seem to work fine tfor me when I do the former. Here's a (slightly edited) transcript of my Bash session:

```
$  declare -A myArray=([emma]="paris london ny" [john]="tokyo LA")
```

Or, to create your associative array on the fly, as in your "actual code",  from the regular arrays called `names` and `cities`, you would first create these arrays, like this:

```
$ declare -a names=(emma john)                     # Notice: small '-a' for inexed array.
$ declare -a cities=("paris london ny" "tokyo LA") # Notice: Quotes around whole lists of cities!
```

Then I would start with an empty `myArray` and build it up in a loop, like this:

```
$ declare myArray=()

for i in ${!names[@]}; do
      name=${names[$i]}
      city=${cities[$i]}
     myArray+=([$name]=$city)
done
```

As an aside: Sometime in the future, you may want to populate `myArray` in this manner, but with different entries in your `cities` and `names`. If and when you do, it will be a good iea to `set -o noglob` before the `for`-loop. This disables pathname expansion by the shell and guards against trouble when you accidentally have a name or city called `*` in one of your arrays. You can re-enable it with `set +o noglob` after the `for`-loop.

Anyway, no matter which way you populate `myArray`, the new cities no longer overwrite the previous, as you can see:

```
$  echo ${myArray[emma]}
paris london ny    

$ echo ${myArray[john]}
tokyo LA
```

And you can process the cities individually, such as in this `for`-loop:

```
$ for city in ${myArray[emma]}; do echo "hello, $city!";  done
hello, paris!
hello, london!
hello, ny!
```

How does that work for you?

PS: I'd like to thank Charles Duffy for the improvements to my code that he suggested in the comments.

Comment: Consider `read -r -a cities <<<"${myArray[emma]}"`; it's not just faster than the `echo | tr` pipeline, it also avoids bugs like a city named `*` being replaced with a list of filenames.

Comment: (That said, `for city in $(...)` will work just as well -- or just as poorly, as it were -- without the `tr` if you have the default `IFS` value, as a space is just as much in `IFS`, and thus used for string-splitting, as a newline is).

Comment: Thanks for the  tip invilving `read`! I have to go to bed now. but tomorrow morning I'll brush up on the read(1) manpage to make sure I know what I'm doing, and then update the post.

Comment: The `read` we want is a shell builtin, so `help read` (or its equivalent content in `man bash`) is a better fit than `man read`; see also [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) when you're back and able to take a look.

Comment: Charles, on reading the Bash documentation, I'll go with your `read` version. But I'll leave out the `-a` and `-r` options because `-a` yields the wrong result nd -r isn't relevant to the example. Also, `for city in $(...)` treats `london paris ny` as one chunk rather than three elements. But thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: If you don't use `-a`, you don't get an array! After `read -r -a arrayname`, `for item in "${arrayname[@]}"` iterates over the items **without** using string-splitting.

Comment: And if `for city in $(...)` treats `london paris ny` as one chunk, either you aren't using bash, or you changed your active `IFS` value to `$'\n'`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, myArray is in a loop ie it's completed dynamically like : while [condition=true ]; do declare -A myArray=( ["$names"]="$cities" ) done

Comment: Im sorry, Charles, but that's the opposite of what I got when I actually tested. I did get an array I could loop over without the -a option, I only got the first element with it.

Comment: @ThomasBlankenhorn, that sounds like you used `$myArray`, not `"${myArray[@]}"` -- if you don't use array syntax for accessing arrays, you only get the first element.

Comment: `read  cities <<<"${myArray[emma]}"` is just a buggy assignment; it doesn't do anything you'd actually *want* that `cities=${myArray[emma]}` doesn't.

Comment: @ThomasBlankenhorn, if you use `declare -p varname`, that'll tell you if the thing is really an array. If it says `declare -- cities="london paris nyc"`, that's not an array at all, it's just a string with spaces in it. If it says `declare -a cities=( [0]="london" [1]="paris" [2]="nyc" )`, **that's** an array.

Comment: You're right, Charles! After removing the superfluous string quotations, I could eliminate the whole `read` business altogether. My code examples are a lot cleaner now, and testing confirmed they still work. Thanks for your patience in helping me get it right! Much appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't quite call that "right", exactly -- you still have a city named `*` replaced with a list of filenames.

Comment: I'm not fully convinced that makes it 'wrong' when the objective is to show a beginner how associative arrays work in Bash. But okay, I've added  a side note about `setting -o noglob` before populating `myArray` and `set +o noglob` after.

Comment: @ThomasBlankenhorn, if you're showing a beginner a string and telling them it's an array? That's *very* wrong; it's teaching a complete misapprehension about what the datatypes actually are.

Comment: Bash is a dynamically typed language. Treating a string like an array may be frowned upon, but that doesn't make it wrong.

Comment: If you at least communicate that that's what you're doing, I may merely frown. Certainly, types change over time as assignments or explicit modifications take place, but at any given time, only a specific set of bits are set on the mask describing the type of a given variable. Something is an array or a string; it is not both at once.

Answer (score 0):

Bash 4 supports associative arrays. But if using Bash 3 or lower, you can roll your own structure by using a regular array, then splitting each element on some separator such as `=`.

```
#!/bin/bash

array=(
  emma="paris london ny" 
  john="tokyo LA"
)

for item in "${array[@]}"; do 
  key=$(cut -d "=" -f 1 <<< "$item")
  value=$(cut -d "=" -f 2 <<< "$item")
  echo "$key=$value"
done
```

Sample output:

```
emma=paris london ny
john=tokyo LA
```

Comment: Why the `cut` usage? That's *very* slow compared to, say, `key=${item%%=*}; value=${item#*=}`.

Comment: That said, the OP here clearly *does* have bash 4 -- they're reporting their values being overwritten, not reporting `declare -A` itself failing with an error. That makes sense -- if they run `declare -A array=( [key]=value )` every time they want to add a new key, that replaces the whole array outright, so it's *expected* to remove all old keys.

Comment: You've made good points. They'll be useful for future readers.

Comment: (Granted, it's a related mistake to declare an array as indexed and have the key treated as a number rather than a string; since any string that maps to an undefined shell variable has the value 0 in a numeric context -- like keys of an indexed array -- one gets the same overwriting-the-value behavior, but distinguishable in that the key was never correctly assigned in the first place, and showed up as 0 in `declare -p array`).

Answer (score 0):

The `declare -A arrayName=( ["key"]="value" )` syntax should only be used when intending to *replace the variable's contents outright*, overwriting all preexisting values to leave only those described in the declaration.

When you want to add new values over time, use `arrayName["$key"]="$value"`. Thus:

```
declare -A arrayName=( )   # Initialize an empty associative array
arrayName["key1"]=value1   # add key1
arrayName["key2"]=value2   # add key2
arrayName["key3"]=value3   # add key3
declare -p arrayName       # print resulting array
```

...has the same result as:

```
# initialize with all three values already present
declare -A arrayName=( ["key1"]="value1" ["key2"]="value2" ["key3"]="value3" )
declare -p arrayName       # print resulting array
```

...whereas the following discards all but the last:

```
declare -A arrayName=( ["key1"]="value1" )  # initialize with key1=value1
declare -A arrayName=( ["key2"]="value2" )  # discard and overwrite with key2=value2
declare -A arrayName=( ["key3"]="value3" )  # discard and overwrite with key3=value3
declare -p arrayName                        # output only has key3 and value3!
```