# How to view syslog entries since last time I looked

Tags: linux, logging, view

I want to view the entries in Linux /var/log/syslog, but I only want to see the entries since last time I looked (preferably create a bash script to do this). The solution I thought of was to take a copy of syslog and diff it against the last time I took a copy, but this seems unclean because syslog can be big and diff adds artifacts in its output. Im thinking maybe somehow use tail directly on syslog, but I dont know how to do this when I dont know how many lines have been added since last time I tried. Any better thoughts? I would like to be able to redirect the result to a file so I can later interactively grep for specific parts of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux has a `wc` command which can count the number of lines within a file, for example
`wc -l /var/log/syslog`.  The bash script below stores the output of the `wc -l` command in a file called `./prevlinecount`.  Whenever you want just the new lines in a file it gets the value in `./prevlinecount` and subtracts this value from a new instance of `wc -l /var/log/syslog` called `newlinecount`.  Then it `tail`s `(newlinecount - prevlinecount)`.

```
#!/bin/bash
prevlinecount=`cat ./prevlinecount`
if [ -z $prevlinecount ]; then
        echo `wc -l $1 | awk '{ print $1 }' > ./prevlinecount`
        tail -n +1 $1
else
        newlinecount=`wc -l $1 | awk '{print $1}'`
        tail -n `expr $newlinecount - $prevlinecount` $1
        echo $newlinecount > ./prevlinecount
fi
```

**beware**
this is a very rudimentary script which can only keep track of one file.  If you would like to extend this script to multiple files, look into [associative arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494178/how-to-define-hash-tables-in-bash). With associative arrays you could keep track of multiple files by having the `key` as the filename and `value` being the previous line count.

**beware too** that over time `syslog` files can be archived after the file reaches a predetermined size (maybe 10MB) and this script does not account for the archival process.