# Parsing a csv to create a hash table in bash results in unexpected functionality

Tags: bash, parsing, hashtable

I'm referencing [How to define hash tables in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494178/how-to-define-hash-tables-in-bash) for my work. I'm attempting to parse a *dict.csv* file containing test data like this:

```
1,orange
2,apple
3,banana sandwich
4,grape juice
5,strawberry
```

And using the Bash 4 solution, creating a key/value dictionary.
Here is my current code (note the key/value in while is inverted, this is intentional):

```
declare -A dict

fileName="dict.csv"

OIFS=$IFS
IFS=','
while read value key
do
    dict+=( ["$key"]="$value" )
done < $fileName
IFS=$OIFS
echo ${dict["orange"]}
echo ${dict["apple"]}
echo ${dict["banana sandwich"]}
echo ${dict["grape juice"]}
echo ${dict["strawberry"]}
```

I would expect my output to be:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

But instead my output is:

```
1
2
3
<blank>
<blank>
```

I noticed that the number of blank lines is equivalent to the number of keys with spaces in them (e.g. `banana salad` and `grape juice`). I'm assuming this problem stems from my misunderstanding of how IFS, the while loop, and parsing in bash work but I'm at a loss to understand what i'm missing.

Thank you for any insights.

Edit: Made a typo in the contents of the dict.csv, 3 now contains `banana sandwich` and not `banana salad` as previously stated. This was a typo in the question and not in my code. My apologies.

Comment: The first step in debugging shell scripts is to put `set -x` at the beginning. Then you'll see a trace of all the commands, with variables expanded.

Comment: The file contains `banana salad`, but you used `banana sandwich` in the script.

Comment: I tried your script I got `1 2 <blank> 4 5`. The blank is because of the above typo.

Comment: Make sure the file ends with a newline. `read` will return an error if the line ends with EOF, although it will still set the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. Thank you for Barmar for pointing this out. My *dict.csv* did not end with a newline which caused a parsing error. There were other issues but they are unrelated to this question. Thank you for the help!