# Checking for a key value pair in the config file using shell script

Tags: shell

I have a configuration file in which I want to check if the the key value pair are present as below and I want them to be a exact match.

> key=value   xxxxx   xxxx

After the key value there can be a space or a tab as shown in the above so I cannot use a simple`grep -q` for getting the key value pair.

Can someone please help me with this

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1494178/1707353) might be helpful.

Comment: `fmt -1 ConfigFile | grep -qxF 'key=value'` or `grep -q '^key=value$ ConfigFile` or `grep -qE '^key=value([ \t].*)?$' ConfigFile`  depending on what you want to happen if you find space/tab

Comment: @jhnc the above command works for me thank you very much. If possible can you please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script like this can extract the `value`:

```
awk '/key/ {split($1,a,"=");print a[2]}' input_file
```

or with variable

```
KEY="key"
awk -v key=$KEY '$1 ~ key {split($1,a,"=");print a[2]}' input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

The below command worked out for me as suggested by @jhnc

> sudo fmt -1 FILEPATH | grep -qxF 'KEY=VALUE'