# Comparing two lists with a shell script

Tags: shell, associative-array

Suppose I have two lists of numbers in files f1, f2, each number one per line. I want to see how many numbers in the first list are not in the second and vice versa. Currently I am using grep -f f2 -v f1 and then repeating this using a shell script. This is pretty slow (quadratic time hurts). Is there a nicer way of doing this?

Comment: Are there dictionaries/hashtables in shell scripting?

Comment: What is the format of the file? One number per line?
Are the characters supposed to represent integers or floats?
Would a python script do?

Comment: Here is some information on associative arrays in bash: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688849/associative-arrays-in-shell-scripts

Comment: One number per line. Integers. I don't actually want a Python script because I am trying to learn more shell scripting. (the original purpose of the shell script was to check my python program was working)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like 'comm' for this sort of thing. 
(files need to be sorted.)

```
$ cat f1
1
2
3
$ cat f2
1
4
5
$ comm f1 f2
        1
2
3
    4
    5
$ comm -12 f1 f2
1
$ comm -23 f1 f2
2
3
$ comm -13 f1 f2
4
5
$
```

Comment: For numerical results it complained that it wasn't in sorted order. --nocheck-order will suppress

Comment: Again, a simple grep and wc can be used to find the actual result

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just put each number in a single line and then `diff`(1) them? You might need to sort the lists beforehand, though for that to work properly.

Comment: Will that actually provide counts?

Comment: Not as such, but you can get that with `grep`/`wc` afterwards. This was just a suggestion on how to improve the quadratic runtime. You will get a somehow (depending on the options to `diff`) readable list of differences. You can just count them, then.

Comment: Okay, will have to play around with this

Comment: diff will have a < for values in the second, but not the first and > for values in the first but not the second. A simple grep and wc should provide the desired answer

Answer (score 1):

In the special case where *one file is a subset of the other*, the following:

```
cat f1 f2 | sort | uniq -u
```

would list the lines *only in* the larger file. And of course piping to `wc -l` will show the count.

However, that isn't exactly what you described.

This one-liner serves my particular needs often, but I'd love to see a more general solution.