# File permissions are not being preserved while after zip

Tags: java, apache, unix, permissions, zip

I am trying to maintain certain file permissions after they are zipped up however, I notice the file permissions are not preserved. Regardless of what I do the file permissions of the unzipped file are always rw-r--r--.

I have tried the following things:

- Setting umask to 0027 in my bash_profile, however, I notice by default the newly created zip file creates permissions for the files of "0022" aka rw-r--r--.
- I have tried setting AsiExtraField with mode 777 and attaching that to ZipArchiveEntry, however, the it does not seem to affect the perms.

> ZipArchiveEntry entry = new ZipArchieveEntry(filename); AsiExtrafield
>   temp = new AsiExtraField(); temp.setMode(777);
>   entry.addAsFirstExtraField(temp); zipoutputstream.putNextEntry(entry);

- For ZipEntries I have tried to setUnixMode() to 777, however, still the unzipped files have a permission of rw-r--r--.

> ```
> ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(filename);
>   entry.setUnixMode(777);
>   zipoutputstream.putNextEntry(entry);
> ```

- Finally I explicitly set the file permissions of a target file before its about to zipped, however, the file perms are not copied over.

> ```
> Runtime.getRuntime.exec("chmod 777" + file.getCanonicalPath()):
> ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(filename);
> zipoutputstream.putNextEntry(entry);
> ```

Help much appreciated!

Comment: Zip does not store file permissions. When you extract files, you create new files. They will have the permissions of the user that performed the unzip. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735297/maintain-file-and-folder-permissions-inside-archives).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis so if I set a umask in my bash_profile should the newly extracted files have the permissions set by the mask? Because even that doesnt seem to be the case. I set a umask of 0027, which would translate to rw-r-----, however when I extract files they seem to have permissions of rw-r--r--. Also what is the typical procedure of setting permissions of extracted files?

Comment: I don't know what `umask` does. Depending on what permissions you want your files to have after extractions, either change user before unzipping or write a script that extracts files and then changes the permissions on the extracted files.

Answer (score 3):

The ZIP format *can* store the unix permissions in "external attributes" field inside the ZIP header.

As an aside I have done this for ZIP files created using the maven-assembly-plugin by using `<fileMode>0755</fileMode>` in the assembly descriptor.

To extract the archive programmatically from Java while also preserving the permissions, there's a nice wrapper around [commons-compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/) called [jarchivelib](http://rauschig.org/jarchivelib/) which supports a number of formats including ZIP, tar.gz. It extracts preserving the UNIX permissions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you will need to try a different archive format. Perhaps `tar --preserve-permissions`.

The other option would be to save the permissions separately and the reapply them upon decompression. You could add a `.saved_permissions` file to the archive. There are some examples of scripts that can do this on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450250/is-it-possible-to-create-a-script-to-save-and-restore-permissions).