# How can I make a Hashmap in Linux shell?

Tags: linux, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to define hash tables in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494178/how-to-define-hash-tables-in-bash)

I wish to create a hash map in a Linux shell script which associates string keys with string values. Is there a simple way I can do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688849/associative-arrays-in-shell-scripts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you shold refer this question:
[How to define hash tables in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494178/how-to-define-hash-tables-in-bash), which is useful. :-)

Answer (score 6):

The environment itself is a hash map that associates string keys with string values.

```
myvar1=myvalue1
myvar2=myvalue2
```

etc.

Or do you need something more?

Comment: Yeha but... Cohesion... I can't just drop colors, animals, numeric, names... into my global variables. It's better to access and modify the variables using a data sctructure...

Comment: @AFP_555 True, but I wouldn't be using bash if I wanted to go that far.