# Replace Environment Variable in argument to shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I've got a shell script that gets called with arguments that contain variable names. I want the variable to be replaced with their values. Consider the example below: It solves my problem, but it uses eval. I want to avoid eval for security reasons.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# example:
# $> replace.sh arg '$VAR'
# arg value

VAR=value
ARGS=$(eval echo $*)

echo $ARGS
```

Comment: That has been bothering me for a long time now, too!!

Comment: seen this? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820343/how-can-i-generate-new-variable-names-on-the-fly-in-a-shell-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me with something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# example:
# $> replace.sh arg '$VAR'
# arg value

VAR=value
ARGS=""
for arg in "$@"
do
  arg="${arg/$/}" # remove preceding $ for indirect variable expansion to work
  ARGS="${ARGS} ${!arg}"
done

echo "$ARGS"
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for indirect variable expansion:

```
$ SPY1=SPY2
$ SPY2="Lance Link"
$ SPY=${!SPY1}
$ echo $SPY
Lance Link
$
```