# Why bash indirect expansion has to use temp variable?

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/10820494/1764881, I know that the standard way of doing it seems to be:

```
   var="SAMPLE$i"
   echo ${!var}
```

But, I can't seem to do any of these following forms. They all failed:

```
echo ${!SAMPLE$i}
echo ${!"SAMPLE$i"}
```

I read the bash man page, but I still couldn't understand. Is it true that the first form is the only form accepted?

Comment: "Why did language X make decision Y?" is a question for the folks who designed the language (mostly, David Korn, since this syntax originated with ksh), and arguably too broad to be a good fit here. "Is it unconditionally true that language X enforces decision Y?", by contrast, is a question to which a simple, concise answer is available: In this case, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The underlying logic is that *all* parameter expansions take a single, literal word as the name of the parameter to expand, and any additional operator does something to the result. `!` is no exception; `var` is expanded as usual, but the *result* is expanded again.

(As an aside, even arrays follow this rule. It might seem that something like `${array[2]%foo}` applies two operators to `array`, but really `array[2]` is treated as the name of a single parameter. There is a *little* difference, as the index is allowed to be an arbitrary arithmetic expression rather than a literal number.)

(And for completeness, I should mention the actual exceptions, `${!prefix*}` and `${!name[*]}`, which confusingly use the same operator `!` for querying variables themselves. The first lists variable names starting with the same prefix; the second lists the keys of the named array.)