# Read n lines from unix file and store each line in a variable

Tags: shell, unix

I have a requirement where I need to store n lines of a UNIX file to n variables. The number of files may vary so I need to use the loop.
eg: A file `abc.txt`

```
table1
table2
table3
```

Now I need to store them in a variable say `Var1,Var2` and `Var3` (here number of lines are not fixed and can change).

Can someone please help me ?

Comment: Are you trying to write shell script in unix which will perform the operations you mentioned in your post?

Comment: yes. I will be writing shell script in unix for that.

Comment: Provide a sample use i/p and o/p for testability

Comment: A sample file would be like. cat abc.txt

Comment: A sample file would be like. cat abc.txt will contain input as                       table1                                                                                                          table2                                                                                                          tablen (Here n is not fixed and may vary).

Comment: Now I want the each line assigned to a variable like Var1,Var2..Varn such that if I echo them                                                                                                    echo $Var1                                                                                                  table 1

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use an array, instead of generating a bunch of variable names? BTW, you didn't mention which shell you want to use.

Comment: @user3568369: Check out my answer below let me know if it helped solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but it should work

```
IFS='\n' read -r -a data <<< "$line"
```

What above command does is, set IFS variable to new line character and do splitting of `$line`. Now for your case `$line` should contain whole file contain and you can get content of each line using ${data[0]},${data[1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16192/what-is-ifs-in-context-of-for-looping)} ...

For more information on IFS you can [click here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16192/what-is-ifs-in-context-of-for-looping)

By default, IFS is set to '\n'.If you want to split based on some other character, `like comma(,)`, change the variable accordingly

Comment: Thanks Ashish. I want each line of the file to be assigned to a separate varable. I could find the maimum line by using wc-l and then for eg: For  4 different lines I want to create 4 variables and assign each line to a new variable like var1,var2,var3 and var4.

Comment: Plz have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820343/how-can-i-generate-new-variable-names-on-the-fly-in-a-shell-script

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of saving it in variable, You can execute your logic at the time of reading line by line from file itself right? If you want to perform certain logic based on the occurrence of string, You can follow some other codes rather than assigning them to different variables / array and iterate them again.

Comment: A very good question, that you should add as a comment to the question.

Comment: Thanks Walter, I am new to this community, And I do not have much reputation to add comment :-) So only added here