# Bash for loop to set a variable, its value, and evaluate it?

Tags: bash, shell

How do I use a for loop to define a variable, *and* its value, *and* be able to evaluate it?

I can't figure out the evaluation part, but using the for loop to define the variable *and* its value seems to work. Specifically,

```
for i in {1..4}
do
    export my${i}var="./path${i}_tofile"
   # or
   # export my${i}var=./path${i}_tofile
   # or
   # eval "my${i}var=\"./path${i}_tofile\""
    echo $[my${i}var]
done
```

The `echo` does not evaluate correctly, but the shell does correctly create the variable and the value.

```
echo $my1var
```

returns

```
./path1_tofile
```

But I need to evaluate the variables using the `$i` as part of their names.

Comment: `my${i}var="./path${i}_tofile"` is *not* valid.  Can you start a new shell and check again?

Answer (score 2):

You should instead use an array variable:

```
declare -a myvar
for i in {1..4}
do
    myvar[$i]="./path${i}_tofile"
done
```

More details: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html

Answer (score 2):

This is how it gets complicated if you *don't* use an array:

```
for i in {1..4}
do
    declare my${i}var="./path${i}_tofile"
    tmpvar=my${i}var             # temporary variabled needed for...
    echo "$tmpvar=${!tmpvar}"    # bash indirect variable expansion
done
```

Comment: This is great. If you could add an explanation for the last part `"$tmpvar=${!tmpvar}"` would be fabulous for such newbies like me :-)

Comment: Check this answer for a nice explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10820497/7552

Comment: Indirect Expansion. Sounds like eval i think.

Comment: No. `eval` will execute potential command substitutions. Indirect expansion will not. Test with this: ``tmpvar='foo`execute nasty command`'; echo "${!tmpvar}"; eval echo "${tmpvar}"`` -- the indirect expansion is essentially "variable not found, substitute the empty string", eval executes the nasty command.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the echo you are using with:

```
v=my${i}var
echo ${!v}
```

Then, the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..4}
do
    export my${i}var="./path${i}_tofile"
    v=my${i}var
    echo ${!v}
done
```

Will execute as:

```
$ ./script
./path1_tofile
./path2_tofile
./path3_tofile
./path4_tofile
```

But, honestly, working with indirect variables is never easy.
Please consider using Indexed arrays (in this use case even normal arrays will work):

```
declare -A myvar

for i in {1..4}
do
    myvar[i]="./path${i}_tofile"
    echo "${myvar[i]}"
done
```

Comment: looks like an array is the way to go - thanks!  I will need to reference the new variables later in the same script, so using an array index is the best method to be able to enter another for loop and re-reference the same variables.  The indirect expansion explanation works great for the current loop and sets the variable values correctly, but doesn't allow me to reference the variables afterward with the same index ...for I in {1..4} loop