# How to set each element from for loop to var in Bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to set each element from for loop to var in Bash.

This is my line:

```
counter=1 ;
for i in $(ls /);
do
    echo line number $counter - $i  ;
    line"$counter"="$i" ;
    echo $(line$counter);
    counter=$[counter+1];
 done
```

What I am trying to do, is set each `i` variable to counted vars (`$counter`).

Comment: How about using an array instead

Comment: All you want is `var=(/*)`.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) reports several problems with the example code.  See [Creating a string variable name from the value of another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716607/creating-a-string-variable-name-from-the-value-of-another-string) for ways to set variables whose names are created on the fly, but you probably should be using an array instead.

Comment: Line breaks were added for readability. Please revert the edit if you disagree.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Bash for loop to set a variable, its value, and evaluate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42047532/bash-for-loop-to-set-a-variable-its-value-and-evaluate-it) (Summary: use an array.) Also, [don't parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).