# Dumping each lines of a command in a distinct variable with bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am currently working on a small script designed for tape backups, and I need the script to search for any tape drive linked to the system. 
I managed to get this part working, and we can see bellow the path of the two tape drives :

```
lsscsi --transport | grep fc: | grep tape | awk -F" " ' { print $4 } '
/dev/st0
/dev/st1
```

*Edit - Here's the raw output of the lsscsi commands :*

```
[1:0:0:0] tape fc:0x50014380032a90b8,0x000001 /dev/st0 
[2:0:0:0] tape fc:0x50014380032a90bb,0x000001 /dev/st1
```

My wish is simply to find a way to redirect each line of the previous output in a new variable (`$drive0=/dev/st0`, `$drive1=/dev/st1`, etc). 
My first attempt looked like this, and isn't working because every lines are dumped into the same variable called `$path_tape`:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/lsscsi --transport | grep fc: | grep tape | while read line ; do
    path_tape=$(echo $line | awk -F" " ' { print $4 } ')
done
```

Now the thing is, there is [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820343/how-can-i-generate-new-variable-names-on-the-fly-in-a-shell-script) that mention a way to increment variables names, so I tried to adapt my code to this solution, resulting in the following lines :

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
/usr/bin/lsscsi --transport | grep fc: | grep tape | while read line ; do
    var="path_tape$i"
    ${!var}=$(echo $line |awk -F" " ' { print $4 } ')
    ((i++))
done
```

But when executed, I now get a syntax error :

```
./test.sh: line 7: =/dev/st0: No such file or directory
./test.sh: line 7: =/dev/st1: No such file or directory
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: post the initial `lsscsi --transport` output

Comment: The two lines would look like this :
`[1:0:0:0]    tape    fc:0x50014380032a90b8,0x000001  /dev/st0
[2:0:0:0]    tape    fc:0x50014380032a90bb,0x000001  /dev/st1`

Comment: move it to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than creating variable names with a numerical suffix to "simulate" an array, you can just use an array in bash.

I think that the best way to do what you want is to use `mapfile`, which turns lines of input into an array. Another name for `mapfile` is `readarray`, you can use either one:

```
mapfile -t path_tape < <(lsscsi --transport | awk -F" " '/tape fc:/ { print $4 }')
readarray -t path_tape < <(lsscsi --transport | awk -F" " '/tape fc:/ { print $4 }')
```

The `-t` option strips the newlines from the array elements. Since we don't have a file, but instead the output of a command, a `<(process substitution)` is used as the input.

Now `path_tape` is an array, whose elements can be accessed like `"${path_tape[i]}"`, where `i` is a number.

As a bonus I shortened your pipeline by combining the grep and awk commands. The structure of an awk script is `condition { action }`, where the condition can be a regular expression match, as in this example.

Testing it out, replacing your command output with a file:

```
$ cat file
[1:0:0:0] tape fc:0x50014380032a90b8,0x000001 /dev/st0 
[2:0:0:0] tape fc:0x50014380032a90bb,0x000001 /dev/st1  
$ mapfile -t path_tape < <(cat file | awk -F" " '/tape fc:/ { print $4 }')
$ printf '%s\n' "${path_tape[@]}"
/dev/st0
/dev/st1
```

Comment: `mapfile` can also be spelled `readarray`, which IMO is more indicative of what it actually does.

Comment: This is even cleaner than what I used before, thanks !   
I never thought about using arrays.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

This will be available as the environment variables path_tape0 and path_tape1 in the shell session

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0;
/usr/bin/lsscsi --transport | grep fc: | grep tape | while read line ; 
  do
      export "path_tape$i"=$(echo $line |awk ' { print $4 } '); env | grep path_tape ;((i++));
  done
```

Comment: Exporting the variables to env might come in handy for the rest of the script, thanks !

Comment: I already have, but sadly my reputation is to low to change the publicly displayed score. Have no doubt that your answer was appreciated !