# Create variable equal to the lines in the file, and assign the variables the value from the file sequentially

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to create a number of variables equal to the lines in a file and assign to each of those variables a value from the file sequentially.

Say,
*file1* contains `device1 device2 device3 .....`
*file2* contains `olddevice1 olddevice2 olddevice3 .....`

I want values as when I do `echo $A = device1`
Similarly `echo $B = device2` and `echo $Z = device26`

I tried a `for` loop, and even an array, but couldn't get through it.

I have tried something like below:

```
iin=0
var=({A..Z})
for jin in `cat file1`
do
   array[$iin]="$var=$jin";
   iin=$(($iin+1));
   var="$(echo $var | tr '[A-Y]Z' '[B-Z]A')"
   printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
done`
```

Comment: I'm almost sure you cannot dynamically create variables. I do not have a source, but the compiler behaviour to assign a variable implies it is explicitly written, as it is then stored in a reference table. Otherwise (as your example shows) you would be assigning, not a variable (which will map to a memory cell), but a content (a letter, a string), and a data value cannot be a reference for a memory (heap, stack...) position. Correct me if I'me wrong

Comment: @samthegolden: The question is tagged `shell` and shows shell script code. Shell scripts are interpreted (at least in effect), and new variables can be created dynamically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I generate new variable names on the fly in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820343/how-can-i-generate-new-variable-names-on-the-fly-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: Please describe what the `$var` variable is meant to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing the point : variables have fix names in programming languages, like `$A`, `$B`, ..., `$Z`: while programming you need to specify those variables inside your program, you can't expect your program to invent it's own variables.

What you are looking for, are collections, like arrays, lists, ...:
You create a collection `A` and you can add values to it (`A[n]=value_n`, or `A.SetAt(n, value_n)`, ..., depending on the kind of collection you're using.

Comment: The question is tagged `shell` and shows shell script code. Shell scripts are interpreted (at least in effect), and new variables can be created dynamically. There may well be a better solution for OP’s actual problem that uses arrays or other features, but what they ask for is possible.

Answer (score 0):

With `bash` (*v4* and later) something like this [`mapfile`](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/bash/mapfile.htm) code should work:

```
mapfile -O 1 -t  array1   < file1  
mapfile -O 1 -t  array2   < file2 
# output line #2 from both files
echo "${array1[2]}" "${array2[2]}" 
# output the last line from both files
echo "${array1[-1]}" "${array2[-1]}"
```

Notes:  `mapfile` just loads an array, but with a few more options.

- `-O 1` sets the array subscript to start at `1` rather than the default `0`; this isn't necessary, but it makes the code easier to read.