# bash one variable for another

Tags: bash, shell, variables, replace

I would like to do in bash something I was doing with perl years ago

$4 (value from a script) can have the value `"S"` or `"U"`

I have:

```
DirectoryU="$Directory/*.$2"
DirectoryS="$Directory/area $3/*.$2"
```

and I want to define "DirectoryC" to something like:

```
DirectoryC=Directory$4
```

but there I dont want DirectoryC=DirectoryU (or DirectoryS) I want DirectoryC to have the value of DirectoryU (or DirectoryS) so after I can base my script on $DirectoryC ...

Does it make sense?

Comment: This sounds like a job for indirect expansion (making it a possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820343/how-can-i-generate-new-variable-names-on-the-fly-in-a-shell-script)), or possibly an associative array (using `Directory["U"]` instead of `DirectoryU`, etc).

Comment: Note that you should probably be using arrays instead of strings (scalar variables in Perl terminology). Trying to store a list of names in a single string will break down the moment any of them has spaces.