# How to update a value in a bash3 associative array?

Tags: bash, dictionary

I would like to modify the value of `louis` to `green` in this bash3 map:

```
ARRAY=( "nicolas:red"
    "louis:blue" )
```

I tried to overwrite with `ARRAY+=("louis:green")` but it does not work: I end up with a 3-elements array with duplicate key.

*Note: I can't use bash4's modern maps so I have to use [bash3 associative arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4444841/226958).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a regular (integer-)indexed array.  You'll have to iterate over it to find the correct index to replace.  (This will also work for adding a new element, as the index will be past the end of the existing array.)

```bash
for ((i=0; i<${#ARRAY[*]}; i++)); do
    [[ ${ARRAY[i]} = louis:* ]] && break
done
ARRAY[i]=louis:green
```