# Create associative array in bash 3

Tags: bash

After thoroughly searching for a way to create an associative array in bash, I found that `declare -A array` will do the trick. But the problem is, it is only for bash version 4 and the bash version the server has in our system is 3.2.16.

How can I achieve some sort of associative array-like hack in bash 3? The values will be passed to a script like

```
ARG=array[key];

./script.sh ${ARG}
```

EDIT: I know that I can do this in awk, or other tools but strict bash is needed for the scenario I am trying to solve.

Comment: Since bash 3 has normal arrays, you will just have to implement associative arrays based on them. But seriously, why would that be necessary?

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/006](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Bash 3 has no associative arrays, so you're going to have to use some other language feature(s) for your purpose. Note that even under bash 4, the code you wrote doesn't do what you claim it does: `./script.sh ${ARG}` does not pass the associative array to the child script, because `${ARG}` expands to nothing when `ARG` is an associative array. You cannot pass an associative array to a child process, you need to encode it anyway.

You need to define some argument passing protocol between the parent script and the child script. A common one is to pass arguments in the form `key=value`. This assumes that the character `=` does not appear in keys.

You also need to figure out how to represent the associative array in the parent script and in the child script. They need not use the same representation.

A common method to represent an associative array is to use separate variables for each element, with a common naming prefix. This requires that the key name only consists of ASCII letters (of either case), digits and underscores. For example, instead of `${myarray[key]}`, write `${myarray__key}`. If the key is determined at run time, you need a round of expansion first: instead of `${myarray[$key]}`, write

```
n=myarray__${key}; echo ${!n}
```

For an assignment, use `printf -v`. Note the `%s` format to `printf` to use the specified value. Do not write <s>`printf -v "myarray__${key}" %s "$value"`</s> since that would treat `$value` as a format and perform printf `%` expansion on it.

```
printf -v "myarray__${key}" %s "$value"
```

If you need to pass an associative array represented like this to a child process with the `key=value` argument representation, you can use `${!myarray__*}` to enumerate over all the variables whose name begins with `myarray__`.

```
args=()
for k in ${!myarray__*}; do
  n=$k
  args+=("$k=${!n}")
done
```

In the child process, to convert arguments of the form `key=value` to separate variables with a prefix:

```
for x; do
  if [[ $x != *=* ]]; then echo 1>&2 "KEY=VALUE expected, but got $x"; exit 120; fi
  printf -v "myarray__${x%%=*}" %s "${x#*=}"
done
```

By the way, are you sure that this is what you need? Instead of calling a bash script from another bash script, you might want to run the child script in a subshell instead. That way it would inherit from all the variables of the parent.

Comment: You can use `printf -v` instead of `declare` to avoid localizing a variable in a function. Sourcing the child script instead of calling it might also be a way of making the parent's arrays and other variables available to the child.

Comment: I don't understand why did you put backspaces in `for k in ``${!myarray__*}``; do` It's not a command.

Comment: @Jocelyndelalande Backspaces?? Oh, I see, backticks. Looks like a copy-pasto, I've fixed it.

Comment: How would you echo myarray__${key} directly instead of assigning it to a variable?

Comment: @rane I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want to avoid the temporary variable `n`? I don't think you can.

Answer (score 12):

Here is another post/explanation on associative arrays in bash 3 and older using parameter expansion:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4444841

Gilles' method has a nice `if` statement to catch delimiter issues, sanitize oddball input ...etc. Use that.

If you are somewhat familiar with parameter expansion:
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

To use in your scenario [ as stated: sending to script ]:
Script 1:
`sending_array.sh`

```
# A pretend Python dictionary with bash 3 
ARRAY=( "cow:moo"
        "dinosaur:roar"
        "bird:chirp"
        "bash:rock" )

bash ./receive_arr.sh "${ARRAY[@]}"
```

Script 2: `receive_arr.sh`

```
argAry1=("$@")

function process_arr () {
    declare -a hash=("${!1}")
    for animal in "${hash[@]}"; do
        echo "Key: ${animal%%:*}"
        echo "Value: ${animal#*:}"
    done
}

process_arr argAry1[@]

exit 0
```

Method 2, sourcing the second script:
Script 1:
`sending_array.sh`

```
source ./receive_arr.sh
# A pretend Python dictionary with bash 3 
ARRAY=( "cow:moo"
        "dinosaur:roar"
        "bird:chirp"
        "bash:rock" )

process_arr ARRAY[@]
```

Script 2: `receive_arr.sh`

```
function process_arr () {
    declare -a hash=("${!1}")
    for animal in "${hash[@]}"; do
        echo "Key: ${animal%%:*}"
        echo "Value: ${animal#*:}"
    done
}
```

References:
[Passing arrays as parameters in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063347/passing-arrays-as-parameters-in-bash)

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to handle a lot of variables, or keys are simply invalid variable identifiers, *and* your array is guaranteed to have *less than 256 items*, you can abuse function return values. This solution does not require any subshell as the value is readily available as a variable, nor any iteration so that performance screams. Also it's very readable, almost like the Bash 4 version.

Here's the most basic version:

```
hash_index() {
    case $1 in
        'foo') return 0;;
        'bar') return 1;;
        'baz') return 2;;
    esac
}

hash_vals=("foo_val"
           "bar_val"
           "baz_val");

hash_index "foo"
echo ${hash_vals[$?]}
```

More details and variants in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688849/associative-arrays-in-shell-scripts/22151682#22151682)

Answer (score 2):

You can write the key-value pairs to a file and then grep by key. If you use a pattern like

```
key=value
```

then you can `egrep` for `^key=` which makes this pretty safe.

To "overwrite" a value, just append the new value at the end of the file and use `tail -1` to get just the last result of `egrep`

Alternatively, you can put this information into a normal array using `key=value` as value for the array and then iterator over the array to find the value.

Answer (score 2):

This turns out to be ridiculously easy. I had to convert a bash 4 script that used a bunch of associative arrays to bash 3. These two helper functions did it all:

```
array_exp() {
    exp=${@//[/__}
    eval "${exp//]}"
}

array_clear() {
    unset $(array_exp "echo \${!$1__*}")
}
```

I'm flabbergasted that this actually works, but that's the beauty of bash. 
E.g.

```
((all[ping_lo] += counts[ping_lo]))
```

becomes

```
array_exp '((all[ping_lo] += counts[ping_lo]))'
```

Or this print statement:

```
printf "%3d" ${counts[ping_lo]} >> $return
```

becomes

```
array_exp 'printf "%3d" ${counts[ping_lo]}' >> $return
```

The only syntax that changes is clearing. This:

```
counts=()
```

becomes

```
array_clear counts
```

and you're set. You could easily tell array_exp to recognize expressions like "=()" and handle them by rewriting them as array_clear expressions, but I prefer the simplicity of the above two functions.

Comment: This looks cool.  Am wondering what do do with statements like:  let 'map[$i]++', particularly the single quotes.  Thoughts/comments?

Comment: In your answer above, the eval statement in array_exp() is failing when I run the script; it's complaining about a "bad substitution"

Answer (score 0):

Ended up creating two arrays:

```
HOST_LIST=(host1 host2)
URL_LIST=(url1 url2)
```

then using the index:

```
for i in ${!HOST_LIST[@]}; do
    echo ${HOST_LIST[$i]} mapped to ${URL_LIST[$i]}
done
```

More useful an extraction function:

```
function GetUrl()
{
    local _HOSTNAME=$1
    local retVal=$2
    for i in ${!HOST_LIST[@]}; do
        if [ "${HOST_LIST[$i]}" = "$_HOSTNAME" ]; then
            eval $retVal="'${URL_LIST[$i]}'"
            return 0
        fi
    done
    return 1
}
```

Called as:

```
GetUrl host2 resultUrl
echo $resultUrl
```