# Associative arrays with space in the key

Tags: arrays, bash

I am trying to create an associative array in Bash in the following way:

```
#!/bin/bash
hash["name"]='Ashwin'
echo ${hash["name"]}
```

This prints the desired output, *Ashwin*, when executed.

But when the key has a space in it,

```
#!/bin/bash
hash["first name"]='Ashwin'
echo ${hash["first name"]}
```

I get the following error

```
test2.sh: line 2: first name: syntax error in expression (error token is "name")
```

Are keys not allowed to have spaces in them?

Comment: Based on your comment to the answer you are using bash 3. Bash 3 does not support associative arrays, here are some [workarounds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776468/create-associative-array-in-bash-3)

Comment: Since associative arrays aren't supported prior to `bash` 4, your first example is actually being treated as a regular array. The parser is able to deal with simple strings where it expects an integer value, and treats them all as having the value 0. You can index `hash` with many different strings and `${hash[key]}` still expands to `Ashwin`.

Answer (score 12):

If you first use `declare -A hash` before the value assignments, then the script runs as expected.

It was tested using Bash 4.2.25.