# shell script associate array value overwriting

Tags: bash, shell, associate

When I run the following shell script always I am getting the output as "grault" for any key.
What would be the problem?

thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a MYMAP                             
MYMAP=( [foo]=bar [baz]=quux [corge]=grault ) 

echo ${MYMAP[foo]}

echo ${MYMAP[baz]}
```

Comment: Run `declare -p MYMAP` to see its actual value.

Answer (score 3):

Create an associative array with `-A`:

```
declare -A MYMAP
```

See: `help declare`

Comment: I am getting following error with -A                                                   associate-array.bash: line 2: declare: -A: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]

Comment: Sorry, your bash has no option `-A`. Add output of `echo $BASH_VERSION`

Comment: @GG You are probably on a Mac.  Associative arrays were added in version 4.

Comment: @GG: Take a look at [Create associative array in bash 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776468/create-associative-array-in-bash-3)

Comment: @GG Your welcome, of course, but it was Cyrus who correctly identified the issues.  To thank him, I suggest that you accept and upvote his answer.   For more information of Stackoverflow's peculiar customs, see: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answer)

Answer (score 1):

The other answer describes how to do it right, but here's the explanation of why your example behaves as it does.

`declare -a` creates an indexed array, which should only accept integers for the index. If you provide a string as the index, it will just disregard it and treat it as a 0! (I think this is a poor behavior, it should just give an error).

So this is what your code translated to:

```
declare -a MYMAP # create indexed array                           
MYMAP=( [0]=bar [0]=quux [0]=grault ) 

echo ${MYMAP[0]} # grault

echo ${MYMAP[0]} # grault
```