# Create Array of File paths with a loop and grep through them

Tags: arrays, string, bash, file, loops

I want to save each output filepath to a variable and then grep through them to find the timestamp. I want to lable each variable by adding the nodeId from the node list I am looping through. When I try this with the following code I get an error

output1_1: command not found

```
nodeList=('1_1' '1_6' '2_1' '2_6')
for i in "${nodeList[@]}"
do
   output${i}=$CWD/output/abc${i}.txt
   times${i}=$(grep  -m 1 '\"path\":' $output${i}| sed 's/.*timestampUtc\"://g' | sed 's/,.*//g')
done
```

Comment: Why not use associative arrays? `declare -A output times`, then `output[$i]=...`

Comment: Instead of `grep -m | sed | sed`, try this (all in one) `sed` command: `sed '/\"path\":/{s/.*timestampUtc\":/\([^,]*\),.*/\1/;q};d'`

Answer (score 0):

As @[muru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2072269/muru) suggested, try

```
declare -A output times
nodeList=('1_1' '1_6' '2_1' '2_6')
for i in "${nodeList[@]}"; do
   output[${i}]=${PWD}/output/abc${i}.txt
   times[${i}]=$(grep  -m 1 '\"path\":' ${output[${i}]} | sed 's/.*timestampUtc\"://g' | sed 's/,.*//g')
done
```

Comment: I am working with bash 3 so unfortunately the terminal wont allow me to do that

Comment: Have a look at [Create associative array in bash 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776468/create-associative-array-in-bash-3)

Answer (score 0):

One way to set a variable whose name is derived from another variable is to use the `-v` option to 'printf'.
To get the value of a variable whose name is in another variable (e.g. `varname`) use `${!varname}`.

See [Creating a string variable name from the value of another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716607/creating-a-string-variable-name-from-the-value-of-another-string) and [How can I generate new variable names on the fly in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820343/how-can-i-generate-new-variable-names-on-the-fly-in-a-shell-script).

Using these a possible loop body is:

```
output_var=output${i}
times_var=times${i}

printf -v "$output_var" '%s' "$CWD/output/abc${i}.txt"
printf -v "$times_var" '%s' "$(grep  -m 1 '\"path\":' "${!output_var}" | sed 's/.*timestampUtc\"://g' | sed 's/,.*//g')"
```

Note that (unless `CWD` is set elsewhere in your program) you probably want `$PWD` instead of `$CWD`.