# foreach loop through associative array in bash only returns last element

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

This should print the whole associative array to the console:

```
#!/bin/sh

declare -a array=([key1]='value1' [key2]='value2')

for key in ${!array[@]}; do
    echo "Key = $key"
    echo "Value = ${array[$key]}"
done

echo ${array[key1]}
echo ${array[key2]}
```

Instead it prints oly the last variable:

```
[mles@sagnix etl-i_test]$ ./test.sh 
Key = 0
Value = value2
value2
value2
```

Where is my fault?

**@htor**:
Bash Version is 3.2.25(1)-release.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/688849/1983854 , there are many solutions to this.

Comment: are you sure /bin/sh is actually /bin/bash?  also associative arrays are built using `-A` not `-a`  ... see answer below

Comment: /bin/sh is a symbolic link to bash on my system

Comment: What's your BASH version? Provide the output of `echo $BASH_VERSION` in your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Associative arrays are supported in Bash 4 and newer versions. An array declared with the `-a` option is just a regular array that can be indexed by integers, not keys. This declaration results in the array with one element `value2`. When iterating over the keys with `for key in ${!array[@]}` the value of `$key` is `0` and therefore you get the first element.

Given the error output you get when trying to use `-A` to declare to array, I assume your Bash version is older than 4. Inspect the variable `$BASH_VERSION`.

For a deeper explaination of arrays, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A array=([key1]='value1' [key2]='value2')

for key in ${!array[@]}; do
    echo "array[$key] = ${array[$key]}"
done

echo ${array[key1]}
echo ${array[key2]}
```

Comment: that gives me an error `./test.sh: line 3: declare: -A: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]`

Comment: @mles: you aren't using `bash` 4 or later.