# Linux Bash Scripting: Declare var name from user or file input

Tags: linux, bash, variables, scripting

Hi i would like to do the following.

```
./script.sh some.file.name.dat another.file.dat

Filename1=$(echo "$1"|cut -d '.' -f 1,2)
Filename2=$(echo "$2"|cut -d '.' -f 1,2)

tempfile_"$1"=$(mktemp)
tempfile_"$2"=$(mktemp)
```

I know this code isn't working. I need to create these temporary files and use them in a for loop later, in which i will do something with the input files and save the output in these temporary files for later usage. So basically i would like to create the variable names dependent on the name of my input files.

I googled a lot and didn't found any answers to my problem.

I would like to thank for your suggestions

Comment: If you `echo $Filename1 echo $Filename2` in script, output will be `some.file` and `another.file`, what seems to be the problem then? you want `some.file.name` and `another.file`

Comment: Just use `tempfile1` and `tempfile2`, the same way you use `Filename1` and `Filename2`.

Comment: Use associative arrays, instead of this **painful** (and possibly _stupid_) way of creating variables. That's what associative arrays were introduced for.

Comment: In the next step i use $1 $2 as iterative in my for loop like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that since Bash just doesn't allow dots in the names of identifiers/variables. Both of your arguments `$1` and `$2` have dots (periods) in them and that cannot be used in variable names you're trying to create i.e. `tempfile_$1`

See [this page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest an alternate solution to use instead of entering the **variable naming hell** you're proposing (Using the variables later will cause you the same problems later, the scale will just be magnified).

Use **Associative arrays** (like `tempfile[$filename]`) instead of `tempfile_"$filename"`. That's what associative arrays are for:

```
declare -A tempfile
tempfile[$1]=$(mktemp)
tempfile[$2]=$(mktemp)

cat ${tempfile[$1]}
cat ${tempfile[$2]}

rm -f ${tempfile[$1]}
rm -f ${tempfile[$2]}
```

Note: **Associative arrays require `bash` version 4.0.0 or newer.**

If you dont have Bash version 4.0.0 or newer, see the following answers for great workarounds that dont use `eval`.

- [How to define hash tables in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494178/how-to-define-hash-tables-in-bash)
- [Associative arrays in Shell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688849/associative-arrays-in-shell-scripts)

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution will work for me. This is a great community, again Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
eval "tempfile_"$1"=$(mktemp)"
eval "tempfile_"$2"=$(mktemp)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
f1=`echo $1|tr '.' '_'`
declare "tempfile_$f1=$(mktemp)"
```

Check out [How to define hash tables in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494178/how-to-define-hash-tables-in-bash)